# popup force to display silverlight 5

Tags: c#, popup, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight 5, C# 
I have two methods on the same class...
first method calls the second to create a POPup.
second method creates a popup

```
 msgWindow = new Popup(); 
  (bla,bla,bla)
```

--- Here is my question: --- 
how can I force it to display after setting

```
msgWindow.IsOpen = true;
```

then return to first method to continue doing other things.
(by the way the popup is displayed after first method finishes).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29714/Silverlight-Wizard

Comment: http://slwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are you asking how the popup can return or notify the caller (`"first method"`)that the user has inputted data or closed the popup?

Comment: Chris - I want to force open the popup after that line.

Comment: Robert...thanks for the links but thought was going to be a simple line (not a proj) answer. any quick answer?